# Using 3.7V li ion batteries in series

Tags: power-supply, batteries, battery-charging, battery-operated, solar-charge-controller

I'm working on a solar powered project which requires two voltage levels - 3.2v-4v @ 2A for one element an 6v-12v @ 500mA for another.

My initial plan was to use a 12v lead acid battery with a solar panel and a charge controller. I would then regulate the voltages. However, the size and weight of lead acid batteries is a bit of a concern for this particular project and so I looked into using a lithium battery. The problem I had with this was that I could only find solar charge controllers for 3.7v lithium batteries, nothing for higher voltage lithium batteries (no decent ones at least).

I came up with the idea of using two 3.7v lithium charge controllers. I could then use one of them to power the 3.2-4v element while also using them in series to power the 6-12v element. Of course the overall Ah rating would be the lowest of the two and they would discharge at different rates. I'm wondering if this is still a feasible solution though. I've added a block diagram of my idea below. I'm open to other suggestions too.[image]

Comment: I think the main thing to look out for would be the possibility that one battery discharges before the other. Have you looked at whether you can use other modules? e.g. can you use a "non-solar" charge controller?

Comment: It’s not an unfeasible solution.  If there’s enough solar power that the cells never run flat then it could be a good solution, but if they might run flat you’d need to satisfy yourself that the resulting condition would be acceptable (one or other cells flat, or both).

Comment: @user253751 Unfortunately it's for an installation away from any sort of mains power which means it has to be solar really. The 3.7V batteries aren't too expensive either so I can get some with fairly high Ah ratings as well.

Comment: @Frog I can get 3.7V batteries with fairly high Ah ratings and solar panels which are able to charge at the maximum rate the system can handle. Besides, the application is not too power hungry anyway. It would also save me having to use regulators and save me a lot of space and weight.

Comment: Not a great idea. Better to map out the current required from each supply, (add that info to the question!) and supply the lower current load from a buck or boost convertor, and choosing the right battery voltage for the higher power load (and capacity to run both of course!).

Comment: @BrianDrummond Thanks for the feedback :) I've added the current requirements to the question. The lower voltage element is actually a cellular module and only uses up to 25mA, but will briefly require up to 2A during data transmission. For this reason, it's recommended that it's powered directly from the battery. Since I can only find solar charge controllers for 3.7V lithium batteries, I figured this was the only solution.

Comment: Brian’s suggestion of using a boost converter is a good one, that way you can have a single cell and a single solar panel. For very low power circuits it’s difficult to get good efficiency from a DC/DC but in this case it looks like a good option.

Comment: @zt42 I didn't say you had to use mains power. I just wondered that, if you can't get a 7.4V solar charge controller, maybe you can get a 7.4V non-solar charge controller and plug it into a solar panel anyway. As far as I know, the term "solar charge controller" is marketing.

Comment: @user253751 Ah ok, sorry I misunderstood. That's not a bad idea and I did look into it. However, I couldn't find a regular 7.4V non-solar charger which allows you to simultaneously connect a load. That feature only seems to be available for the 3.7V battery chargers which takes me back to square one.

Comment: @Frog Thanks for your input :) It does make sense in terms of efficiency and practicality. But if you see in the comment above, I've struggled to find any suitable 7.4V charge controllers, even non-solar ones.